# Is there any case where we have to declare a class as static in java?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

please i want to understand if there are some cases where we have to declare a class as static in java. I really dont say any need to declare a class static in java.

thanks in advance,

Comment: When you want nested class belong to the outer class rather than to an instance of the outer one.

Answer (score 4):

Outer classes in java cannot be static. The use case for a static class is an inner class. For example:

```
public class OuterClass {

    static class InnerClass { }

}
```

If the inner class does not reference any members or non-static methods from the outer class, the inner class can be static. It's more efficient from a memory usage perspective if you have a lot of instances of `OuterClass`, and it de-couples `InnerClass` from `OuterClass`, making it easier to split out into its own class if needed.

Comment: Plus, the inner class _must_ be static (which was OP's question) if you want to create an instance of it without it being bound to an instance of the outer class.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an inner class static to provide better organizational structure.  The two classes are treated independently but allows you to see the clear relationship with the outer class.  If you declare an inner class static then it cannot reference any members or non-static methods of its outer class though.

For example, `Map.Entry` is an inner static class.  If it were just called `Entry` then the relationship to the `Map` class might not be so clear.

edit: As Ted Hopp mentioned a static class does not need an instance to the outer class in order to be instantiated since the classes are essentially treated as separate.